# Why can't I get the status of this radio button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code from a salesforce visualforce page.

```
<div id="testId" class="row mb25 mt15">
    <div class="col-md-6 plr0">
        <p class="en">Would you like to add a co-applicant?<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </p>
        <p class="fr">Would you like to add a co-applicant?<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-5r">
        <apex:selectRadio id="innerTestId" value="{!client.Would_you_like_to_recieve_future_promo__c}" styleClass="radio">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="radio pa-cus">
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="radio pa-cus">
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="No" itemValue="No"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the Submit button is clicked I need to have a JQuery script to check weather the radio button is selected `Yes` or `No` so that I can perform some custom validation. I call this function by adding `onclick="validateInnerTestId();"` to Submit button.

My problem is that I am unable to read/check whether the radio button is chosen Yes or No or True or False. If I can find out what state they are in then I can do my

Here is my goal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>                                                                                 
    function validateInnerTestId()
    {
        if(innerTestId is Selected as Yes)
        {
            execute fucntionX()
        }
        else
        {
            execute functionY()
        }
    }
<script>
```

Here is some examples of how I have tried to read the value of the radio button:

`alert($("#innerTestId").itemValue());` this line doesn't return anything

`alert($("#innerTestId").val());` this line also doesn't return anything

and this `if else` always return `no`

```
if ($('#innerTestId').is(':checked'))
{
    alert("yes");
}
else
{
    alert("no");
}
```

Does anyone has any idea on how to check for the radio button in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Programming questions not specific to Salesforce are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Hi, this is a Salesforce questions. Please see my html. FYI - I also have this question in other forum and I was mentioned to ask here because they weren't able to help. [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984141/why-cant-i-get-the-status-of-this-radio-button-in-jquery)

Comment: you are asking a question related to javascript, just because there is an apex tag in your markup doesnt make it salesforce specific.

Comment: @glls This is salesforce specific. Hold on a sec, I got this.

Comment: Imo it look more like jquery/javascript related

Comment: @sfdcfox -> right click inspect element, and the OP might have figured it out, debugging 101, related to SF yes, but the question is mostly related to jquery javascript imo. I Hope CB4 learned something today =)

Comment: @sfdcfox, I might have been a bit hasty to vote to close, a simple explanation as to why as an answer like you did would have been more appropriate =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce "mangles" your "id" values to make them globally unique. That means you can't reliably query for them by ID directly. Instead, you'll need to query using the "contains" operator:

```
if($('input[id*=innerTestId]').is(':checked')) {
```

As a shorthand, if you were looking for a *specific* checked value, you could also do:

```
if(document.querySelector("input[id*=innerTestId][value='Yes']:checked")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as:

```
$("[id$='innerTestId'] :radio").click(function(){
    alert('---> '+$(this).val() );
});
```

Here in selector **[id$='innerTestId']** is looking for All elements with a Id attribute value ending with "innerTestId" and after this **:radio** is to filter radio buttons within the element found via ID.

Comment: $= won't work with selectRadio, because each value will be suffixed with a number, as in "innerTestId:0", "innerTestId:1", etc.

Comment: Haha You know it worked as [id$='innerTestId'] is returning as table id is coming as "j_id0:j_id1:innerTestId" and after that I have :radio check so it is working fine. I tested it in my dev org before posting here.